# scala play - edit JsValue with nested JsValues

Tags: json, scala, playframework

the question is not specific for JsValue, its for all the immutable objects in scala which i want to edit part of it and keep the rest as is.
for example i have this object:

```
"references": {
    "hsId": "37395615-244b-4706-b6f5-237272f07140",
    "others": {
      "path": "rewr",
      "externalId": "ewr",
      "version": "2"
    }
}
```

and lets say i just want to edit the version.

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ok i figured out a way of solution,
but i feel its a patch and not the best answer

```
val references: JsObject = (json \ "references").as[JsObject]
val newVersion = JsObject(List(("others", JsObject(List(("version", JsString("3")))).as[JsValue])))
val newReferences = references.deepMerge(newVersion)
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use [JSON transformers](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.3.x/ScalaJsonTransformers). Let's say we want to change the version to `"3"`.

```
val js: JsValue = Json.parse("""
    {
        "references": {
            "hsId": "37395615-244b-4706-b6f5-237272f07140",
             "others": {
                 "path": "rewr",
                 "externalId": "ewr",
                 "version": "2"
             }
        }
    }
""")

// Define the transformer
val transformer =  (__ \ "references" \ "others").json.update(
   __.read[JsObject].map{o => o ++ Json.obj("version" -> "3")}
)

val newJs = js.transform(transformer)
```

This will copy the entire object, then replace `version` on the `others` branch.